# How to make multiple input and output at MS-Function Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, simulink

I made a function in Matlab who create automaticaly blocks of input and output.

I have a **M-S-Function** and these output and input blocks.

Now I want to connect with line these input and output with M-S-Function and I don't know how to do that.

How to add more input and output ports at M-S-Function ?

Like this:

[image]

That need to be generated in a function, programmatically.

Comment: Are you talking about an m-code S-Function?  If so, the number of inputs and outputs are defined in the m-code (and wouldn't be changed programmatically).  You'd join the inport blocks to the inports of the S-Function using `add_line`.

Comment: I tried with add_line but that S-Function don't have 2 or more inputs and outputs,he have just one input and output, I want to add more inputs and outputs to that function. Is that possible ?

Comment: If it's a level-1 m-code S-function (which you should not be writing) then it will only ever have 1 inport, and you need to `mux` the signals together before putting them into the S-Function block.  If it's a level-2 m-code S-Function then the number of ports won't be set until the block gets initialized (so the model looks at the code and sees how many inputs and outputs it needs to work).  You'll probably need to force an initialization to get that this to work.

Comment: It is a level 2 S-Function.How can I do that initialization with code?

Comment: `modelname([],[],[],'compile')`  will force a recompile.  This must be followed by `modelname([],[],[],'term')` to release it.